# Should i use Tegra for setting up environment to develop android app?

Tags: android, installation, development-environment

i am going to use the environment to develop apps using opencv library. But first i may also use it to develop some basic core Android Applications. Should i use the automatic TADP installer to set up the environment or should i set up things manually?